# How to use std::find to find a string from the first elements of a vector< pair < string, string > > type?

Tags: c++, lambda

I tried the following code :

```
    auto it = find(v.begin(),v.end(), name, [](const pair<string, string> &a,const string b)
                           {
                               return a.first == b;
                           }); // name contains the string to find.
```

But this gives me compilation error. Help me find out my mistake.

Comment: _"But this gives me compilation error."_ is a bit vague. Can you show what's the exact verbatim _compilation error_? `std::find()` doesn't allow to pass a lambda comparator IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload you are trying to call does not exist. You want to use [find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(), [&](const pair<string, string> &a)
{
    return a.first == name;
}); // name contains the string to find.
```

Comment: What does the & stand for in [&]. I wondered how the lambda function would recognize "name" if I don't even pass it in find_if and the lambda function. Surprisingly for me, putting an & solves this problem. Why?

Comment: @Sami It's a [lambda capture list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) that captures everything in scope by reference.

Comment: @Sami Alternatively, if you want to be more explicit, you can also specify `[&name]`.